# assign value to a variable in a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists in the format

```
list = [["text1",index_value1],["text2",index_value2],["text3",index_value3]]
```

In a for loop I want to assign values to index_value1, index_value2, ...

If I do

```
list[0][1] = 5
```

I would replace index_value1 in the list with 5 instead assigning the value 5 to index_value1.
How can I assign the value to the variable instead of replacing the variable in the list.

I could change the list to

```
list = [["text1","index_value1"],["text2","index_value2"],["text3","index_value3"]]
```

If this simplifies the solution.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The (reference to the) _value_ is in the list, not the identifier. I'd recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: there are no "variables" in the list. lists contain *objects*, not variables

Comment: Almost any time you are tempted to use variables with names determined by code is a smell that you should probably use a `dict`, a `list` or another collection object instead. Don't use `index_value1`, use `indices[0]`, or `indices["text1"]`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want a assign a variable like a array or an dictionary ? without that it replace the indexvalue variable  with a value you provided.

```
index_value1 = None

index_value2 = None

index_value3 = None

list1 = [["text1", index_value1], ["text2", index_value2], ["text3", index_value3]]

for val in list1:

    val[1] = 5

print(list1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround using Python dictionary, as you cannot assign a value to a variable in a list without declaring it first.

```
dict = {
  0: {"id": "text1", "index_value1": None},
  1: {"id": "text2", "index_value2": None},
  2: {"id": "text3", "index_value3": None}
}
```

To assign a value:

```
dict[0]["index_value1"] = 5
```